# Why can't I get anywhere from Cleveland via Amtrak?

Tags: usa, trains, planning, amtrak

I was looking at travelling to and from Delaware, and the closest Amtrak station to me is in Cleveland. To my surprise, however, it said there were absolutely no routes between the two places! I tried DC and New York as well, and nothing. Is the site only giving me direct routes, or is there really no way to get anywhere at all from Cleveland?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing something wrong -- Cleveland has [daily direct service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleveland_Lakefront_Station) to both [Washington DC](http://www.amtrak.com/capitol-limited-train) and [New York](http://www.amtrak.com/ccurl/991/310/Amtrak-Lake-Shore-Limited-Train-Route-Guide.pdf).

Comment: Huh. Must have been something about the day I was entering as a search, I picked a random day and looked again and it found a train. Maybe something to do with some of their routes closing this summer for repairwork. Thanks!